# Backup and restore all registry

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, registry

I want to backup and restore all registry settings.

Is there any windows api to backup and restore all registry?

Where registry settings are saved in disk?

%USERPROFILE%\NTUSER.DAT - This path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these pages [RegSaveKeyExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsavekeyexa),[RegRestoreKeyA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regrestorekeya).

Might be helpful.